# Is this the correct way to use private variables in the functions of the same class?

Tags: java

I'm creating a program to calculate the density of an object, I'm using 2 separated java files which are the Density class and the main class. I declared all the data needed as private and use it in several functions which will be nested in a function that will be called in the main class, my problem is I'm not sure if this is the right way to use private variables other than using getter and setter. (the program has been successfully compiled)
Below is some parts Density.java :

```
class Density{

Scanner DataDensity = new Scanner(System.in);  // use this scanner for Density class
private double Mass;
private double Volume;
private double Density;

// Calculates Density
public void CalculateDense(){
    System.out.println("Mass (Kg) : ");
    Mass = DataDensity.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Volume (m^3) : ");
    Volume = DataDensity.nextDouble();
    Density = Mass/Volume;
    System.out.println("Density : "+Density+"Kg/m^3\n");
}
// And another calculating functions.
// This function below will be the only function used in the main class
public void getDataDense(){
    char Input;
    System.out.println("p : density\nm : mass\nv : volume\nq : back to main menu\n");
    boolean Iteration = true;
    while(Iteration){
        System.out.println("Your Choice : ");
        Input = DataDensity.next().charAt(0);
        if(Input=='p'){
            // call "CalculateDense" here.
            CalculateDense();
        }
        else{
        System.out.println("Your choice is not available\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Below is some parts of the main class :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
while(Continue){
 System.out.println("Enter one of the number on the menu : ");
 int MainChoice = MainInput.nextInt();
     if(MainChoice==1){
        // Density,Mass,Volume (Density.java)
        Density DensityOb = new Density();
        DensityOb.getDataDense();
    }
    else{
      // some statements
   }
}
```

Any answer will be appreciated

Comment: What's wrong with getters/setters? (I mean the *right way* **is** to use them)

Comment: In Java variable names and method names should be in camel case. Don't start it with capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a proper way. It is encapsulation. CalculateDense can also be private.

Answer (score 0):

setting your attributes private keeps them safe but you do not really need all these attributes in your class, attributes should not be calculated from other attributes without a clear change of state, if one attribute (which other attributes depends on) got changed without triggering the change logic you will have inconsistent in your data, thats just my opinion.

Another thing having the scanner inside the object is not good for example if you want to change the way of ready (from file ), at least if you really need to read data inside method in your object you can pass the scanner in the constructor or the method, you can read more about dependency injection.

And please take care of the conventions , attributes are camelcase.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine as long as the program is run with one thread. You might face problems if multiple `threads` use the same `object`. E.g. you have two methods in the class:

- CalculateDense
- getDataDense

Now, imagine the scenario that two threads are using the same object. One threads calls `CalculateDense` whereas the other thread calls `getDataDense` at the same time. As `CalculateDense` is still being exeuted, you will get `exception` or inconsistent results in the second thread.

Ideal practice would be to create an immutanle object (e.g. the one that accepts `Mass`, `Volume` and `Density` and make `CalculateDense` return a number rather tha initialising reference varialbles). Another practice would be to create `Scanner` locally and `close` it after method execution finishes.

You can read more about threads [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/threads.html).